# example for mocks and stubs in cxxtest

Tags: stubs, cxxtest

I am using cxx test for unit testing. I have the proper setup for everything and I have written test cases for some simple functions but with a lot of dependencies in the code, I am finding it difficult to write more test suites. I have searched thoroughly on Google about mocks and stubs but still, i don't have a complete feel of mocks and stubs.I would like to have some proper examples of projects which are using mocks and stubs. any proper GitHub link will also work. Or any proper explanation will also be very much useful.